# How to skip source parent directory using grunt uglify

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

**src directory:**

```
dir1
|-- 1.js
|-- 2.js
`-- sub-dir1
    `-- 1.js
```

**dest directory:**

```
min
`-- dir1
    |-- 1.min.js
    |-- 2.min.js
    `-- sub-dir1
        `-- 1.min.js
```

**My code snippet:**

```js
uglify: {
    t2: {
        options: {                    
            banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> - v<%= pkg.version %> - ' +
                    '<%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */'
        },
        files: [{                    
            expand: true,
            src: ['dir1/**/*.js'],
            dest: 'min',
            rename: function (dst, src) {                        
                return dst + '/' + src.replace('.js', '.min.js');                        
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

But I want to skip source directory under destination directory, desired structure is:

```
min
|-- 1.min.js
|-- 2.min.js
`-- sub-dir1
    `-- 1.min.js
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways to achieve this. *Solution A* (below) is the simplest and most commonly used.

---

**Solution A**

When building the files object dynamically you can utilize the [cwd](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically) property. The description of the `cwd` property in the docs reads:

> `cwd` All `src` matches are relative to (but don't include) this path.

Change your `files` property to the following:

```js
// ...
files: [{
  expand: true,
  cwd: 'dir1/',    // <-- Add this.
  src: '**/*.js',  // <-- Change your src glob to this.
  dest: 'min',
  rename: function (dst, src) {
    return dst + '/' + src.replace('.js', '.min.js');
  }
}]
// ...
```

---

**Solution B**

Another way, (without utilizing the `cwd` property), is to change your `rename` method to the following instead:

```js
// ...
rename: function (dst, src) {
    src = src.split('/');
    src.shift();
    src = src.join('/');
    return dst + '/' + src.replace('.js', '.min.js');
}
// ...
```

- The **`src = src.split('/');`** part utilizes the String [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method with the `/` separator to split the `src` path into an array of individual path items.
- The **`src.shift();`** part utilizes the Array [`shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) method to remove the first element from the array (e.g. `dir1`).
- The **`src = src.join('/')`** part utilizes the Array [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method with the `/` separator to form the new path as a String.